# How to Find and Replace Multiple Values in a String with PHP

Tags: php, string, laravel, variables

I'm building a templating system that uses pre determined fields (named field 1 - 10) and a corresponding form to switch out those fields with the users form data. I've been playing around with preg_replace and str_replace but am unsure of how to correctly implement this feature as I have never used it before.

Essentially the system works by first uploading a 'template' which is a string of html formatted like so

```
'<div><h1>{field1}</h1><h2>{field1}</h2></div>'
```

In a separate function I want to replace the '{field1}' and '{field2}' values with the strings submitted through the user form.

So far I am pulling in the data as shown below:

For the Template:

```php
$html = Templates::where('id', '=', $templateId)->get('html');
```

For the Form Data:

```php
$field1 = $request->input('field_1');
$field2 = $request->input('field_2');
```

I then want to do something like the code below, but am unsure of the syntax. As I've not used preg_replace before I am writing each field from one to ten manually as separate functions.

Ideally I'd like to be able to loop through each field from 1 to 10 check if they appear in the $html as '{field#}' if the field exists in the template then replace with the form data and if not just ignore it. As to save re writing the code for each separate field.

Current Replacement Attempt:

```php
$htmlPrep =  preg_replace('{field1}', $field1, $html);
$htmlPrep =  preg_replace('{field2}', $field2, $html);
```

The reason for replacing those areas of the string within the function, rather than rendering them in place within the view, is that the fields1-10 and generation system first of all needs to work for multiple templates that will have any number of fields limited to a maximum of ten, And secondly the $htmlPrep variable containing the result of combined data will not be rendered, but sent to an API with some CSS in order to generate and return an image.

So the expected result (using 'a' and 'b' as the user input form values) would be a new variable named $htmlPrep which contains:

```
 '<div><h1>a</h1><h2>b</h2></div>'.
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  There are plenty of template engines out there for php. What's the use case here?

Comment: The curly braces in your patterns will be interpreted as pattern modifiers, not literal curly braces.  `str_replace()` can receive an array of finds and replacements.  The variable naming mistake makes this an Iff-topic: Typo question.

Answer (score 0):

**Surely you can use:**

```
$htmlPrep = str_replace('{field1}', $field1, $html);
```

**Instead of:**

```
$htmlPrep = preg_replace('{field1}', $field1, $html);
```

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer in my question, I have already tried str_replace. At the moment I am echoing out the string to test whether the variables have changed, both 'str replace' and 'preg_replace' don't appear to be changing the specified sections of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a doofus and overlooked a fairly simple error in the code logic.

So I was trying to insert all the values into one string. But each time I ran the string replace for one variable I used the original html template '$html' rather than the updated '$htmlPrep', since I had written a field3 line of replacement code and there was not a field3 in my testing template it would take the original $html look for '{field3}' not find it it, and then return the original string with no replacements into my new variable.

In Short,

This:

```php
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field1}', $field1, $html);
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field2}', $field2, $html);
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field3}', $field3, $html);
```

Should have been this:

```php
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field1}', $field1, $html);
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field2}', $field2, $htmlPrep);
$htmlPrep =  str_replace('{field3}', $field3, $htmlPrep);
```